# Certbot autorenew failed during Github outage

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

Today I had a certbot autorenew failure. The cron script to renew the certificate failed, and my certificate expired. Below is the log, which includes at the end me ssh'ing into the box to manually run the `certbot-auto renew --standalone --no-self-upgrade` command to fix the issue.

My questions are - does this show the source of the certificate renewal error? Did it have something to do with today's GitHub outage, or was it another issue? What can I do to avoid this in the future?

This is the cron job that runs the renewal script (le-renew.log is the name of the below logfile):

```
30 2 * * 1 /usr/local/sbin/certbot-auto renew >> /var/log/le-renew.log
```

le-renew.log:

```
...(more duplicate logfile entries above)
Get:21 http://http.debian.net jessie/main Sources [7,054 kB]
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en
Get:22 http://http.debian.net jessie/main amd64 Packages [6,789 kB]
Get:23 http://http.debian.net jessie/main Translation-en [4,582 kB]
Fetched 1,083 kB in 9s (113 kB/s)
apt-get update hit problems but continuing anyway...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
augeas-lenses is already the newest version.
libaugeas0 is already the newest version.
gcc is already the newest version.
libffi-dev is already the newest version.
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
openssl is already the newest version.
python is already the newest version.
python-dev is already the newest version.
python-virtualenv is already the newest version.
virtualenv is already the newest version.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ca-certificates
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 83 not upgraded.
Need to get 207 kB of archives.
After this operation, 92.2 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
Bootstrapping dependencies for Debian-based OSes... (you can skip this with --no-bootstrap)
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie InRelease
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com jessie InRelease
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
Get:2 http://http.debian.net jessie-updates InRelease [145 kB]
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie Release.gpg
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie Release
Get:3 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Sources [762 B]
Get:4 http://http.debian.net jessie-updates/main Sources [15.7 kB]
Get:5 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main amd64 Packages [966 B]
Get:6 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Get:7 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Get:8 http://http.debian.net jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [8,392 B]
Get:9 http://http.debian.net jessie-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [3,196 B]
Get:10 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Get:11 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Get:12 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
Get:13 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Get:14 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en
Get:15 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Get:16 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en_US
Get:17 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en
Get:18 http://http.debian.net jessie/main Sources [7,054 kB]
Get:19 http://http.debian.net jessie/main amd64 Packages [6,789 kB]
Get:20 http://http.debian.net jessie/main Translation-en [4,582 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en
Fetched 221 kB in 9s (23.8 kB/s)
apt-get update hit problems but continuing anyway...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
augeas-lenses is already the newest version.
libaugeas0 is already the newest version.
gcc is already the newest version.
libffi-dev is already the newest version.
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
openssl is already the newest version.
python is already the newest version.
python-dev is already the newest version.
python-virtualenv is already the newest version.
virtualenv is already the newest version.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ca-certificates
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 70 not upgraded.
Need to get 207 kB of archives.
After this operation, 92.2 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
Upgrading certbot-auto 0.13.0 to 0.16.0...
Replacing certbot-auto...
Creating virtual environment...
Installing Python packages...
Installation succeeded.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
new certificate deployed without reload, fullchain is
/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Congratulations, all renewals succeeded. The following certs have been renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem (success)
```

Comment: Your log shows no certbot failures, just apt logs.

Comment: @captncraig that's what I had thought - but the renewal definitely failed. Where might I find the correct log? Or is the 404 of the apt log the culprit?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/56811/342069 may help find cron output

Answer (score 2):

The biggest thing that jumps out to me is that you have an operational problem here:

> **Today** I had **a** certbot autorenew failure. The cron script to renew the
>   certificate failed, **and my certificate expired**.

Why are you waiting until the last possible day to renew? You can run certbot daily, and it will renew anything expiring in the next 30 days. That should give you a lot more time to diagnose and react to single issuance failures.

You should also be **monitoring** the cron job for failures. Either with an external service, or by somehow notifying on failure from the cron job. Perhaps try the answers [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/54152/how-to-get-e-mail-from-failed-cron-jobs-in-ubuntu).

Comment: interesting - my cron job _does_ run every Monday - I've updated my question to include the cron job and the script it runs. I had thought that this would only renew on the expiration date but if your comment is correct then the renewal appears to have been failing every Monday for the past 30 days...

Comment: Then you have a monitoring problem as well. I personally just run [caddy](https://caddyserver.com), which manages certs and renewals automatically.